# How to call method multiple times in the same time

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, junit

I need to write some test which will call my method multiple times in the same time, is it possible using MvcMock or something?

I want to achieve the same result as I achieved using curl & curl & curl in bash ( run multiple curl requests asynchronously ) - my method throws Optimistic locking exception because each request modify the same entity, but all my tests are green.

I know the solution ( locking with PESSIMISTIC ) and it works fine, but I have no idea how to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything that blocks using basic Java multi threading?
Something like

```
    ExecutorService EXEC = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Callable<String> c = () -> {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return "";
    };
    tasks.add(c);
    tasks.add(c);
    tasks.add(c);
    List<Future<String>> results = EXEC.invokeAll(tasks);
```

(replace Sys out with call of your method)